# How do I split a delimited file without /n?

Tags: php, parsing, fopen

I have this data :

```
920-1063-03@0001D92E@2012-07-02 920-1063-04@00002F5F@2012-07-02 920-1063-04@00002453@2012-07-02 920-1063-03@0001D256@2012-07-02 920-1063-03@0001E225@2012-07-02 920-1063-03@0001E3C1@2012-07-02 920-1063-04@00001EA6@2012-07-02 920-1063-03@0001D316@2012-07-02 920-1063-04@00002A41@2012-07-02 920-1063-04@00001ADA@2012-07-02 920-1063-04@00002DFD@2012-07-02 920-1063-03@0001C595@2012-07-02 920-1063-04@00001C24@2012-07-02 920-1063-04@00002341@2012-07-02 920-1063-04@00001645@2012-07-02 920-1063-04@00001C04@2012-07-02
```

Which I am trying to split delimited by the `@` sign.

To do this I have this code:

```
<?php
    $filename = "tru_cage_DSB_sn";
    $fd = fopen ($filename, "r");
    $contents = fread ($fd,filesize ($filename));

    fclose ($fd); 
    $delimiter = "@";
    $splitcontents = explode($delimiter, $contents);
    $counter = "";
    foreach ( $splitcontents as $color ){ 
    $counter = $counter+1;
    echo "<b>Split $counter: </b> $color<br>";
    }
?>
```

The output will be like this :

```
Split 1: 920-1063-03
Split 2: 0001D92E
Split 3: 2012-07-02 920-1063-04
Split 4: 00002F5F
Split 5: 2012-07-02 920-1063-04
```

However, I would like the split to also separate `2012-07-02 920-1063-04` into two strings, delimited by space. So the output should be like this?

```
Split 1: 920-1063-03
Split 2: 0001D92E
Split 3: 2012-07-02
Split 4: 920-1063-04
Split 5: 00002F5F
Split 6: 2012-07-02
Split 7: 920-1063-04
```

How do I split this further?

Or, is there a way to directly insert these data to a mySQL database with 3 columns?

Comment: Why not just read line by line instead?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, how do i do that?

Comment: tip: your whole fopen/fread/filesize business can be replaced with `$text = file_get_contents('name_of_file');`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`preg_split`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) instead of `explode` to split on a regular expression consisting of either of the delimiters you want to use:

```
$delimiter = "/@| /";
$splitcontents = preg_split($delimiter, $contents);
```

Also, you should probably initialize `$counter` to `0` instead of to the empty string.

---

Or, as [Ignacio commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241445/how-do-i-split-a-delimited-file-without-n/12241462#comment16407452_12241445), use [`fgets`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) to read the file line-by-line.

Comment: Thanks Matt! Your code works, however, it doesn't split the content, rather, the output is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$text = '920-1063-03@0001D92E@2012-07-02 920-1063-04@00002F5F@2012-07-02 920-1063-04@00002453@2012-07-02 920-1063-03@0001D256@2012-07-02 920-1063-03@0001E225@2012-07-02 920-1063-03@0001E3C1@2012-07-02 920-1063-04@00001EA6@2012-07-02 920-1063-03@0001D316@2012-07-02 920-1063-04@00002A41@2012-07-02 920-1063-04@00001ADA@2012-07-02 920-1063-04@00002DFD@2012-07-02 920-1063-03@0001C595@2012-07-02 920-1063-04@00001C24@2012-07-02 920-1063-04@00002341@2012-07-02 920-1063-04@00001645@2012-07-02 920-1063-04@00001C04@2012-07-02';

$matches = preg_split('#[@\s]#msi', $text);

if (count($matches)) {
    $counter = 0;
    foreach ( $matches as $color ){ 
        $counter = $counter++;
        echo "<strong>Split $counter: </strong> $color<br/>\n";
    }
}

?>
```

Output:

```
<strong>Split 1: </strong> 920-1063-03<br/>
<strong>Split 2: </strong> 0001D92E<br/>
<strong>Split 3: </strong> 2012-07-02 <br/>
<strong>Split 4: </strong> 920-1063-04<br/>
<strong>Split 5: </strong> 00002F5F<br/>
```

EDIT: I've used `preg_split` as Matt mentioned, much simpler.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way that I can generate a csv file out of the output? Or maybe insert it directly to a mySQL DB with 3 columns?

Comment: The CSV option would be through fputcsv: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php